# How compiler understand java 8 compile jar in to Java 6 Compile java class file

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I have a jar file which is compiled in java 8, and I am writing  java code in java 6 environment which should consume the java 8 compiled jar.

How it is possible - how can the compiler understand the new features of java 8(Method definition in Interface, lambda expression etc) ?

Comment: A Java 6 runtime environment will not understand Java 8 specific features, so running your Java 8 code on Java 6 is not going to work.

Comment: I am not executing my code yet, i just written my code in eclipse using java 6 compiler, and consume java 8 compiled jar.

Comment: If you are not executing? Then what are you looking for?

Comment: If the jar was compiled using `-target 1.6` (or lower) then the Java 6 JRE will be able to use it, but then the author of the jar cannot use language features that only work on Java 8 or newer. There is no magic, where Java 6 can suddenly understand Java 8 features.

Comment: Rewrite your Java 8 class to use only java 6 features and recompile it using the -target 1.6 feature to run it on a 1.6 vm with other 1.6 classes OR run 1.8 classes with 1.6 classes on a 1.8+vm.  Nothing else is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can **not** do that.

Java8 contains syntax that a Java6 compiler does **not** know.

There are projects like [Retro lambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda/blob/master/README.md) designed to allow you to use Java8 features on older JVMs. But you can't change the java6 compiler to magically know how to deal with java8 source code.

And when using retro lambda, the point is: there is always a certain chance that some specific thing will not work as you expect it to work. And beyond that: you will have to look for yet another replacement when thinking about using the Java8 date-time APIs.

In other words: getting "Java8" working in a Java6 environment is always an *uphill* battle. It can result in a lot of work, and a lot of pain. Meaning: before going down this path - rather spent some time evaluating if it isn't **cheaper** in the long run to move your environment to use Java8. You will have to anyway at some point.

Comment: thanks for answer, My question is something different, I am not looking to use java 8 feature in java 6. But my question is How java 6 compiler can use java 8 featured class

Comment: @Afgan It cannot. The JDK 6 compiler cannot compile source code with Java 8 language features.

Comment: @Afgan See my updates - Jesper is correct - what you are asking for is not possible.